# why cant I create an array attribute as a type parameter in java

Tags: java, class, types, type-parameter

I want to create an array like this:

```java
public class Population<T> {
    T[] a = new T[10];
}
```

However, the complier throws me this error:

```
Type parameter 'T' cannot be instantiated directly
```

Why does this happen, and what can I do to overcome this issue?

Comment: Use a list instead

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this directly, as the compiler has mentioned. Giving an answer that fits your case is not straightforward since there are no implementation details.

One possibility is to inject an array/list/collection via a constructor.

```
public class Population<T> {
    private final List<T> members; 
    public Population(List<T> members) {
        this.members = members;
    }
}
```

and then use becomes

```
List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
Population<Animal> population = new Population(animals);
```